# $(a_{n})$ converges to $0$, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_{n}}{n}$ converges?

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

Is it true that if a sequence $(a_{n})$ converges to $0$,
then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_{n}}{n}$ converges?

I worked with some small examples and thought it may be true.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Check convergence of $a_n=1/\ln(n)$ for $n>1$ (let $a_1=a$ any arbitrary finitie constant) using Cauchys Integral criterion (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think Cauchy condensation test is comparatively easy to prove this series is divergent

Comment: That is also one valid possiblity to proof the divergence. But I prefere the integral criterion because it is easy to remember and to proof :).

Answer (score 1):

In fact if $\sum b_n$ is any divergent series of positive terms, there exists a positive sequence $a_n \to 0$ such that $\sum a_n b_n $ diverges.

Proof: There exist integers $1= n_1 < n_2 < \cdots$ such that

$$\sum_{n=n_k}^{n_{k+1} -1} b_n > 1.$$

For each $k$ define $a_n = 1/k$ on the block $n_k\le n < n_{k+1}.$ Then

$$\sum a_n b_n = \sum_k \sum_{n_k\le n < n_{k+1}} a_n b_n = \sum_k \,(1/k)\sum_{n_k\le n < n_{k+1}} b_n \ge \sum_k 1/k =\infty.$$

Comment: OK, who's the genius who down voted this?